# wait for code inside ajax request done to finish to then do something

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following code:

```
var requestEvents = getEvents();

requestEvents.done(function (resp1) {

    $(resp1).find('events').each(function() {
        var event_id = $(this).find('id').text();
        var event_name = $(this).find('name').text();
        var event_description = $(this).find('description').text();
        var event_start_date = $(this).find('startDate').text();
        var event_end_date = $(this).find('endDate').text();

        count++;
        if (count >= 2) {
            // This will execute after the first request is done
            var requestParticipants = getParticipants(event_id);
            var requestPlaces = getPlaces(event_id);
            var requestMedia = getMedia(event_id);

            $.when(requestParticipants, requestPlaces, requestMedia).done(function (resp2, resp3, resp4) {
                participants.push(resp2[2].responseText);
                media.push(resp3[2].responseText);
                places.push(resp4[2].responseText);

                var new_event = {
                    'id' : event_id,
                    'name' : event_name,
                    'description' : event_description,
                    'start_date' : event_start_date,
                    'end_date' : event_end_date,
                    'participants' : participants,
                    'pictures' : media,
                    'places' : places
                };
                events.push(new_event);

                console.log(resp2[2].responseText);
                console.log(resp3[2].responseText);
                console.log(resp4[2].responseText);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

everything is working as i expected, althugh i need to perform more code when the code within .done as finished.

I tried with

```
.then( function(){

});
```

but this runs before all events are put inside the array.

I need something that waits for all events to be put inside event array which is not happening right now. How can i achieve this?

ajax call methods:

```
function getEvents(){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://"+server+":"+port+"/remember-me/rest/events?user="+ user,
        dataType : "xml"
    });
}

function getParticipants(event_id){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://"+server+":"+port+"/remember-me/rest/events/"
        + event_id + "/participants",
        dataType : "xml"
    });
}

function getMedia(event_id){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET", 
        url: "http://"+server+":"+port+"/remember-me/rest/events/"
        + event_id+ "/media",
        dataType : "xml"
    });
}

function getPlaces(event_id){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET", 
        url: "http://"+server+":"+port+"/remember-me/rest/events/"
        + event_id+ "/places",
        dataType : "xml"
    });
}
```

Comment: Are your `get*` methods all returning `Deferred` objects? (I assume they're aliases to some `$.ajax` call?)

Comment: yes they are ill post them. @BradChristie pls check my edit

Comment: no, @guest271314 i make 1 request that gives me several events. for every event i make 3 requests. i want that code to finish before i perform my last piece of code.

Comment: `length` of `events` array at completion of `x` (all) requests ?

Comment: i can know that. post ur solution with events.length if u want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way? Use `$.Deferred` and generate your own deferred object (a finalizer) and `resolve` it when all operation(s) have completed. Basically:

```
var requestEvents = getEvents();
var finalizer = $.Deferred(); // ADDED

requestEvents.done(function (resp1) {
    var unfinishedEvents = $(resp1).find('events').length; // ADDED

    $(resp1).find('events').each(function() {
        /* ... */

        count++;
        if (count >= 2) {
            // This will execute after the first request is done
            var requestParticipants = getParticipants(event_id);
            var requestPlaces = getPlaces(event_id);
            var requestMedia = getMedia(event_id);

            $.when(requestParticipants, requestPlaces, requestMedia).done(function (resp2, resp3, resp4) {
                /* ... */
            })
            .then(function(){                 // ADDED
                if (--unfinishedEvents == 0){ // ADDED
                    finalizer.resolve();      // ADDED
                }                             // ADDED
            });                               // ADDED
        }
    });
});

finalizer.done(function(){    // ADDED
  /* ... */                   // ADDED
});                           // ADDED
```

Example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/j8o2y88z/3/ (observe the console). To see it randomize how many events you have, see http://jsfiddle.net/j8o2y88z/4/

Comment: it is not entering the finalizer.done code, the problem is that unfinishedevents never gets to 0 in my case gets to 2 e think it has to do with the speed of how it processes requests. never resolving the finalizer

Comment: It worked my bad. i have 1 event i dont count so it has to be == 1 now its working. thx

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Approach to define single `$.ajax()` request with a single function ; storing request settings in a single array . `url` , or other parameters (e.g., `data`) passed to `request` function. Utilize scope of `.each()` to loop through array of settings , pushing data to `events` array.  When `events` array `length` equals `length` of settings or `requests` ( `urls` at jsfiddle) `length` , utilize `.always()` callback to perform other tasks.

Try

```
..
            $.when(requestParticipants, requestPlaces, requestMedia)
            .done(function (resp2, resp3, resp4) {
                participants.push(resp2[2].responseText);
                media.push(resp3[2].responseText);
                places.push(resp4[2].responseText);

                var new_event = {
                    'id' : event_id,
                    'name' : event_name,
                    'description' : event_description,
                    'start_date' : event_start_date,
                    'end_date' : event_end_date,
                    'participants' : participants,
                    'pictures' : media,
                    'places' : places
                };
                events.push(new_event);

                console.log(resp2[2].responseText);
                console.log(resp3[2].responseText);
                console.log(resp4[2].responseText);
            })
            // `always` , or `complete` callback 
            // i.e.g., `10` : actual or expected `events` array` `.length` 
            .always(function() {
              if (events.length === 10) {
                // do stuff
                // when `events` `.length` === total requests 
                console.log(events.length);
              };

            })
..
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/z66otnc6/

Comment: This also works but it enters in always every time so i accepted top response. although this works too so +1

Comment: @João Note, the `if` statement could be placed inside of the `done` callback , returning same results http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/z66otnc6/5/ . Although `deferred.always()` does appear to actually fire _after_ `deferred.done()` . Arrangement of piece at post is re-arrangeable between `done` or `always` ; pattern at post utilized , here , to separate `deferred` callbacks' tasks ; e.g., `done` : do stuff , `always` : complete doing stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Brad Christie's answer is correct, then the following simplifications will also be correct .... and significantly more elegant.

First some objectives :

- avoid the need for outer arrays for the accumulation of results
- avoid the need to create and resolve an explicit `$.Deferred()`
- avoid the need for a manually decremented `unfinishedEvents`
- avoid the need for a manually incremented `count`
- reduce the volume of "flow control" code
- purge unnecessary assignments.

Here's the flow-control in bare-bones form :

```
getEvents().then(function (resp1) {
    return $.when.apply(null, jQueryCollection.map(function(item, i) {
        ...
        return (i < 2) ? null : $.when(p0, p1, p2).then(function(a0, a1, a2) {
            return {...};
        });
    }).get());
});
```

*Notes :*

- *Replacing `.done()` with `.then()` in two places and making appropriate returns, allows for progressive filtering. `.done()` is a dead-end method that, while functional in its own right, does not contribute to a promise chain*
- *`.get()` is necessary because `jQueryCollection.map()` returns another jQueryCollection.*

The full code is still reasonably concise :

```
var promiseOfEvents = getEvents().then(function (resp1) {
    return $.when.apply(null, $(resp1).find('events').map(function (event, i) {
        var $event = $(event),
            event_id = $event.find('id').text();
        return (i < 2) ? null : $.when(getParticipants(event_id), getPlaces(event_id), getMedia(event_id)).then(function (a0, a1, a2) {
            return {
                'id' : event_id,
                'name' : $event.find('name').text(),
                'description' : $event.find('description').text(),
                'start_date' : $event.find('startDate').text(),
                'end_date' : $event.find('endDate').text(),
                'participant' : a0[2].responseText,
                'picture' : a1[2].responseText,
                'place' : a2[2].responseText
            };
        });
    }).get());
});

promiseOfEvents.then(function () {
    // now compose `events` from the arguments
    var events = [].slice.apply(arguments);
    // work with `events` here
});
```

*Notes :*

- *Outer member `events` was never necessary. Even with the original code, the required data could (and should) have been made available via the promise chain*
- *Outer members `participants`, `media` and `places` were never necessary. Even with the original code, individual data items could (and should) have been included as properties of `events` without using outer arrays.*